# how to calculate width of all li in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have one `ul` and inside that I have `li`'s  .My `ul` has `max-width` is `400` .I want to show only few `li`' (till `400px`) after that i want to show `More link`.when user click on `more link` it will display remaining `li`.so I want to calculate width of `li` element so that I can break my `li`'s (before more li and remaining li).can we calculate the `li` and compare always the total `li` width with `400px` if it is reached or not.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-stonebraker-usly9?file=/src/styles.css

I am able to get width of `parent` (400px) but I want width of all `li`  present inside the `ul`

```
export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const navRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (navRef) {
      console.log(navRef.current.offsetWidth);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="cls">
      <ul className="nav" ref={navRef}>
        {links.map(({ text, url }, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={index}
              className={[`${index === activeIndex ? "active" : ""}`].join(" ")}
            >
              <a data-target="rc64panel_2" href={url}>
                <span>{text}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am calculating width because I want to know how many element I will show before more and remaining I want to know In pop up
Thanks @KS . updating
Example
Let take a example I have 5 li's . using css it how 3 li . how I will know 2 is remaining ? let take I want to show remaining item in pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with pure `CSS` and just replace the class when you need to.

```
.cls {
   max-width: 400px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And when you don't need this class anymore (on button click) you just remove it.

```
// you store the class name in the state
const [classes, setClasses] = useState('cls')
// 
const handleShowMore = () => {
  setClasses('') // or anything else
}
...

return <div>
 <div className={classes}>your li go here</div>
 <button onClick={handleShowMore}>show more</button>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
You can get the hidden ones by accessing the ref that you already have.

```
[...navRef.current.children].forEach((item, index) => {
  item.offsetWidth // will get you the li width
})
```

now you can either get the indexes of the items, or move them to the node that you want to display them in (div in the modal) with appendChild.

Comment: @ks thanks for answering .but how to know how many remaining element left

Comment: let take a example I have `5 li's` . using css it how `3` `li` . how I will know 2 is remaining ? let take I want to show remaining item in pop up.

Comment: You should update the question with these requirements.

Comment: that why I am trying to calculate width so that I can take a variable in state till it it show .and remaining I will show in pop up.sure I will update that

Comment: @Ks it is possible or ?

Comment: @user944513 it is possible, but not the cleanest of solutions. Better to make it all with CSS and then know for sure how much space one item takes. So that you can split the array of items in two and show them in separate places.

Answer (score -1):

You could get each li width before putting them in the dom, sum them and when threshold is met you hide rest of the elements until user clicks *More link*

The simplest approach

```js
const links = [
  {
    text: "Technology",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
  {
    text: "Beauty",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
  {
    text: "Construction",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
  {
    text: "Manufactoring",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
  {
    text: "Transportation",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
  {
    text: "Real Estate",
    url: "placeholder.html"
  },
];

const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;



const App = () => {
  const [clickedMore, setClickMore] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => setClickMore(true);
  
  const renderListItems = function*() {
    const widthThreshold = 200;
    let totalWidth = 0;
    let index = 0;
    for(const link of links) {
     
     const test = document.createElement("li");
     test.textContent = link.text;
     test.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     test.style.position = 'absolute';
     document.body.appendChild(test);
     const offsetWidth = test.offsetWidth;
     test.parentNode.removeChild(test);
     
     const style = {
      display: "list-item",
     }
     
     if(!clickedMore && totalWidth + offsetWidth > widthThreshold) {
      style.display = "none";
     }
     
     totalWidth += offsetWidth;
     
     yield (<li style={style} key={index}>{link.text}</li>);
     
     index++;
     
    }
  }

    return <div><ul className="nav">
      {[...renderListItems()]}
    </ul>
    {clickedMore ? null : <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>More link</button>
    </div>}
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.cls {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: calc(44px - 0.9em);
}

.nav > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.12.1/polyfill.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>
```